# Sparql query subPropertyOf

Tags: sparql, semantics, semantic-web, protege

This is a small ontology to get the color combination and their reviews
For example (red combinesWith black and hasReview "perfect Match")
Is there a better way of doing this?
I'm trying to query SubPropertyOf. 
Is it possible to do- :hasReview rdfs:subPropertyOf :combinesWith .

Thank you

```
PREFIX : <http://myexample#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
SELECT ?color ?colorcode ?coc ?review ?description
WHERE   { 
    ?color rdf:type :Color;
                  :Code  ?colorcode .
        {SELECT ?coc
    WHERE {
        ?color :combinesWith ?coc .
       //here I would to get the value of hasReview 

      :hasReview rdfs:subPropertyOf :combinesWith .
    }
} 
}
```

Comment: I don't think `subPropertyOf` means what you think it means. You seem to be looking for declaring a property that applies to a whole triple, which is not supported in RDF graphs. You will have to identify a color combination with an IRI of its own, and then link both colors, as well as the `hasReview` property, do that IRI. Also, in general, a triple pattern without any variables, like your statement `:hasReview rdfs:subPropertyOf :combinesWith .`, does not make much sense in the `WHERE` part of a SPARQL query.

Comment: Hi Mapper please could you help me with a small example in how I can link these 2 colors and show the review? Thank you

Comment: Could you provide a link to your ontology so that this discussion will go easier?

Comment: This is a link to my ontology https://www.dropbox.com/s/sirwo767d6lrkzw/colors.owl?dl=0  I've just started learning about protege and ontology. I trying to find the best way to query all colors that combine and the ones that do not with their respective review. I can make it work just for two colors using a object property, but if I have (Green combineWith Brown Red and blue and hasreview "Perfect combination", "Too dark colors") then becomes really complicated. Will be grateful with any help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I will first try and juxtapose how I imagine your idea of the meaning of `subClassOf` (feel free to correct me if my impression is wrong) and its actual meaning, and then go on to explain how you might achieve what you are looking for instead.

---

For your `:combinesWith` property

```
?color :combinesWith ?coc .
```

let's assume the following small dataset:

```
:red :combinesWith :yellow .
:red :combinesWith :purple .
:green :combinesWith :yellow .
:green :combinesWith :white .
:green :combinesWith :black .
:white :combinesWith :silver .
:white :combinesWith :black .
:black :combinesWith :white .
```

---

Apparently, you assume that a subproperty of a property *X* is a property that applies to triples whose predicate is the property *X*. In concrete terms, in the above dataset, you seem to think you are able to assign a review to each of those combinations, something like (pseudo-code, no valid syntax!):

```
{ :red :combinesWith :yellow } :hasReview "a combination of warm colors" .
{ :green :combinesWith :yellow } :hasReview "nature, sunflowers" .
{ :black :combinesWith :white } :hasReview "too much contrast for my taste" .
```

---

Actually, however, a subproperty *Y* of a property *X* can be understood in a way so that for all triples whose predicate is property *Y*, there is also a triple with the same subject and object whose predicate is *X*. Or, in a slightly different interpretation, when you're looking for triples whose predicate is *X*, you will find all triples whose predicate is *X* and all triples whose predicate is *Y*. It works in an analogous way to subclasses.

So, for the above dataset, what might be reasonable is to declare a new property `:combinesPerfectlyWith`, which is a subproperty of `:combinesWith`. Like this, you could change the dataset to something as follows:

```
:red :combinesWith :yellow .
:red :combinesPerfectlyWith :purple .
:green :combinesPerfectlyWith :yellow .
:green :combinesWith :white .
:green :combinesWith :black .
:white :combinesWith :silver .
:white :combinesWith :black .
:black :combinesWith :white .
```

You are not losing any information here, you are just further specifying some information.

---

Now, back to what you actually seem to want to do - assign one or more reviews with color combinations.

To do so, the actual review (or at least an indicator of its presence?) will be the object of your review-related triples, and you will have to have *something* that can be the subject. That *something* needs to be another IRI or blank node, one that represents the color combination.

Therefore, you may want to redefine your ontology in a way that there is a `:ColorCombination` type with properties like `:color` and `:hasReview`. An excerpt of the dataset might then look as follows:

```
_:cc1 a :ColorCombination ;
    :color :red ;
    :color :purple .
_:cc2 a :ColorCombination ;
    :color :red ;
    :color :yellow ;
    :hasReview "a combination of warm colors" .
...
```

---

Now, in your SPARQL query, you can fetch the values with some straightforward triple patterns. I am not entirely sure what your query is intended to do, given that your nested `SELECT` query exports only the variable `?coc`, which is not connected to your restrictions in the outer query.